# invalid type (list) for variable 'i'

Tags: r, function

I am trying to fit a function to some gas-production data. Using the nls function I can get good results from a single column of data, but want to use the apply() function to use the equation over my whole dataset. I created the function (france.model()) below, but it only works when I input both the data-frame and specific column (dataframe$column).

I can get the apply() function to interate the correct number of times, but it uses the first column, which isn't much use.

My script is as follows:

```
Timex<-c(0,  3,  6, 12, 24, 42, 60, 86)
#
model<- nls(TotalMay$C11 ~ A-(B*(Q^Timex)*(Z^sqrt(Timex))), 
            data = TotalMay,
            start = list(A = 251.5, B = 251.5, Q = 0.98, Z = 0.92))
summary(model)
```

This is just to show that the equation itself works ok. But then, in order to put this into an apply(function, I need to turn the equation itself into a function:

```
france.model <- function(i){nls(i ~ A-(B*(Q^Timex)*(Z^sqrt(Timex))), 
                          data = i,
                          start = list(A = 251.5, B = 251.5, Q = 0.98, Z = 0.92))
summary(model)}
```

Which I want to run so that I can slot a dataframe into the function(i)

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
> france.model(TotalMay)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~i, data = i) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'i'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Called from: model.frame.default(formula = ~i, data = i)
```

'TotalMay' is a datafram that I want to use, running the nls model by column.

I then need to fit this function into an apply() function as follows:

```
apply(TotalMay, MARGIN = 2, FUN= france.model(i))
```

From what I can tell, apply FUN= won't let me specify the dataframe in any case.

Comment: I suggest you reshape the data to long format and use the `nlsList` function from package nlme.

Comment: By 'long format' do you mean in rows instead of columns?

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.18637/jss.v059.i10 Table 3 shows an example of "long format". You should have three columns: time, y and a factor variable distinguishing your "treatments", i.e., assigning the time/y value pairs to what you have encoded as different columns.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've put the model together but, there appears to be something I'm doing wrong. I'm getting an 'unexpected ',' error, yet when I delete the offending ',', it comes back with unexpected 'data'! Here is the line of code: Gasnlm <- nlsList(y ~ A-(B*(Q^Timex)*(Z^sqrt(Timex)), data = TotalMayLong, start = c(A = 251.5, B = 251.5, Q = 0.98, Z = 0.92)))
                  summary(Gasnlm)

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis at the wrong position and should include the grouping factor (separated with an `|`) in the formula.

Comment: It worked, many thanks. I had to first create a 'groupedData' object which I called 'MayTot', fitted that to the 'data=' entry in the nlsList function and it gave me exactly what I wanted. For interest, here's my script:                                                                                                         MayTot<- groupedData(y~Timex|Treatment, data = TotalMayLong)

Gasnlm <- nlsList(y ~ A-(B*(Q^Timex)*(Z^sqrt(Timex))), data = MayTot, start = c(A = 251.5, B = 251.5, Q = 0.98, Z = 0.92))
                  summary(Gasnlm)